# print function not producing the correct results

Tags: java, arrays

I am trying to print the results of the results of my code and it is working when I am simply printing out the results in a straight line but I want the results to be printed in a figure 8 diagram. Below shows the code that effectively prints the results in a straight line:

```
public void printActivities () {      
   // print all the train activity history  
   System.out.println("TRAIN TRACK ACTIVITY(Tracks [0..18])");  
   for (Enumeration <String> e = theActivities.elements() ; e.hasMoreElements(); ) 
      System.out.println(e.nextElement());
}// end printActivities
```

and the results that this returns is:

```
Train [A1] moving/moved to [5]

 [..][..][..][..][..][A1][..][..][..][..][..][..][..][..][..][..][..][..][..]

Train [A1] moving/moved to [6]

[..][..][..][..][..][..][A1][..][..][..][..][..][..][..][..][..][..][..][..]
```

but below shows the code that I have created to print out the figure eight but there are no results being returned. So does anyone have an idea why this is not outputting my results?

```
public void printActivities(){
String tempString="";
   // print all the train activity history  
   System.out.println("TRAIN TRACK ACTIVITY(Tracks [0..18])");  
   for (Enumeration <String> e = theActivities.elements() ; e.hasMoreElements(); ) 
      System.out.println(e.nextElement());
   tempString="\t" + trainTrack[5]+ "\n"+ trainTrack[4] + "\t\t" + trainTrack[6] + "\n"+ trainTrack[3] + "\t\t" + trainTrack[7] 
          + "\n"+ trainTrack[2] + "\t\t" + trainTrack[8] + "\n"+ trainTrack[1] + "\t\t" + trainTrack[9] + "\n\t" + trainTrack[0]
        + "\n"+ trainTrack[10] + "\t\t" + trainTrack[18] + "\n"+ trainTrack[11] + "\t\t" + trainTrack[17]   + "\n"+ trainTrack[12]
                + "\t\t" + trainTrack[16] + "\n"+ trainTrack[13] + "\t\t" + trainTrack[15] + "\n\t" + trainTrack[14];
   System.out.println(tempString);
}// end printActivities
```

after runing this code I get the following result but with no information returned within the array positions:

```
         [..]
[..]        [..]
[..]        [..]
[..]        [..]
[..]        [..]
         [..]
[..]        [..]
[..]        [..]
[..]        [..]
[..]        [..]
     [..]
```

Comment: Put a break point at the line "System.out.println(tempString);" does tempstring have anything in it?

Comment: Where do you declare `trainTrack` in the figure 8 attempt?

Comment: it is devlared at the beginning of the class 'private String[] trainTrack;'

Comment: So, you have no train on tracks 0-18. Have you moved it to some of them? What should be the correct result?